# Single Micro SD card used Raspberry Pi Zero being seen as two images on a MacBook Pro

Tags: mac, raspberry-pi, macbook, sd-card

After I loaded NOOBS onto my 8GB micro SD card and booted from it on my Raspberry Pi Zero, my MacBook Pro recognizes the SD card as being 2 different images.

[image: Image of how my computer sees the disk]]

How do I get it back into one image so that I can put a new OS onto it using my macOS? I have found plenty of answers for Windows, none working for macOS.

Comment: It is [totally normal](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/wiki/NOOBS-partitioning-explained) to have 2 partitions. You just need to delete both partitions, create a new one and put your files in. As I don't use MacOS, can't give further advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launch `/Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility`

First, make sure View menu > Show All Devices is selected.

You'll see all your mounted drives now are show hierarchically inside other 'containers' with reveal arrows.

Select the topmost 'container' of your SD card - the actual device name itself 'SanDisk12345' or 'Generic SD/MMC' or whatever, not any of the volume names.

Click Erase.

For Mac usage, choose GUID/HFS+ [Extended, Journalled, is HFS+]

[image]